# Python 3.3 doesn't work properly on OS X Maverics

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, osx-mavericks, python-idle

I installed python 3.3 in my new Macboook Pro Retina Late 2013 with OS X Maverics, when I tried to execute IDLE, the window appears and disappear instantly. When I tried to do the same from the terminal

```
open -a /Applications/Python\ 3.3/IDLE.app
```

Then it throws:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Python 3.3/IDLE.app with error -10810.
```

When I tried to execute a simple tkinter window, is the same behaviour (window open and close)

```
from tkinter import *

f = Frame()
f.pack(padx=15, pady=15)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is some background on that error code: http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html . Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: Are you using the latest Python (3.3.3) from python.org with the latest ActiveTcl (8.5.15.0)?

Comment: I'm gonna try this at home tonight, amazing community!!

Comment: "Are you using the latest Python (3.3.3) from python.org with the latest ActiveTcl (8.5.15.0)?"

How do I get python3.3 to use ActiveTcl 8.5.15?

Answer (score 2):

It is a know issue with Mavericks. See http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/